# Find Pixel values in circular ROI

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm creating a circular region of interest ( arc). But struggling to find the pixel values  present in this ROI?

Any help on this would be highly appreciated

Comment: 1) Could you explain what you are trying to achieve ? (mouse hit-testing ? do you need to know the pixel color ?) 2) Could you show what you tried already ?

Comment: Use Pythagoras theorem to find if an [x,y] point is inside your circle: (x-centerX)^2 + (y-centerY)^2 < radius^2. Then use `context.getImageData` to fetch the pixel data for your circle-points. Start with these hints. Then try some coding and come back with any coding problems you experience.

Comment: As a side note to @markE's comment, the context2D method isPointInPath() might show useful also.